Can we avoid the use of Volatile in Singleton Pattern by making the getInstance() method synchronized in Java?
In most places, this is the implementation followed for Singleton Design Pattern.
It makes use of the keyword volatile to prevent the issue of partial object creation (establishes happens-before relation between reads and writes to instance).
public class Singleton {
    private volatile static Singleton instance;
    private Singleton() {}
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

I was wondering if we could avoid the usage of volatile by making the entire getInstance() method synchronized? If it does not work, how would the execution of both cases differ?

You can avoid every synchronization by simply using private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton(); and public static Singleton getInstance() { return instance; } This is already thread safe, lazily initialized, and as efficient as it can get. It’s annoying that this unnecessarily complicated and inefficient double checked locking is popping up every now and then. It’s useless.

If you really want to use a Singleton use the Initialization-on-demand holder idiom.

@RaduSebastianLAZIN even this pattern is unnecessarily complicated. The initialization of the outer class is as lazy as the initialization of the inner class (to the JVM, there is no difference between inner classes and top level classes). Just do as described in my first comment and the initialization will be done on the first invocation of getInstance(). The linked article confuses “loading” and “initialization”. See this answer.

This answer may also help.

@Holger you are wrong, the static inner class is only initialized (also as per your link) when the getInstance method is called hence the memory for the singleton is only allocated at that time, when in your example the memory is allocated when the Singleton class is loaded (and initialized) by the class loader.

@RaduSebastianLAZIN follow the provided links, which cite the specification. A class is initialized only on certain actions, like the invocation of getInstance(); there is no mystical “initialization by the class loader”. As already said, there aren’t different rules for inner classes, the JVM doesn’t even know the concept of inner classes. You could even make the instance field public and remove the method, as the same principle that the nested class is initialized on the first access to its static field applies to the top level class as well.

@Holder you are right but (as I mentioned) in your example the memory for singleton instance allocated even if you call another static method in the Singleton class as for in my example it is not. And the question shows that this is the intended behavior so that the memory is only allocated when the getInstance method is called.

@RaduSebastianLAZIN that’s an entirely different topic. In the question’s code, there is no other static method and it’s strongly discouraged to add other unrelated static members. It’s the Single Responsibility principle. I do not agree that the question’s code indicates the intention to add other static methods, the code rather indicates that the author followed bad advice, as the double checked locking never served any purpose. Yes, if you want to add other static members, moving the singleton’s field to a nested class would be useful. But moving those other static members would be better

BTW synchronized (Singleton.class) is similar to making the static method synchronized (just avoiding it to be done every time the method is called, that is, once the instance is not-null, no synchronization is done/needed)

@RaduSebastianLAZIN BTW, your comment "the memory for singleton instance allocated even if you call another static method in the Singleton class as for in my example it is not" is also not correct regarding your example -  the nested class in your linked "Initialization-on-demand holder idiom" will also be loaded if "you call another static method in" that nested class (just the classes being able to do so are more restricted - but same can be done with the Singleton class)

The downside of making the entire method synchronized is that you introduce a synchronization bottleneck for all calls, even if the singleton has long since been initialized.

Implementing Singleton with an Enum (in Java) public enum MySingleton {     INSTANCE;     private MySingleton() { … } }

@MarkRotteveel | In my understanding (please correct me if I'm wrong) , if thread A is processing the Object Creation line instance = new Singleton();, what adding the 'volatile' keyword does is, it prevents thread B from accessing (read/write) to the variable (instance) before thread A completes processing.

In this case, the first if (instance == null) wouldn't execute for thread B when thread A is still creating the object, so it shouldn't matter if the object is already created or not - we couldn't possibly read it's value unless thread A completes its processing. Thus, it should not make a difference in performance if we make the entire method synchronized, isn't it?

@SoumyaSen No, volatile establishes a happens-before between the write of the value and subsequent reads. It ensures that all readers, even when not in a synchronized block, see the latest update to the field. Volatile does not prevent or block access, that is what mutual exclusion like the synchronized block are for. The result is that the read outside the synchronized is guaranteed to see the last write (otherwise it is entirely possible that other threads always read null), as a result threads do not need to enter the synchronized block at all if initialization has been done.

Not having to enter the synchronized block avoids a concurrency bottleneck, because only one thread at a time can enter any synchronized block on a specific object (the monitor). So imagine 100 threads want to get the singleton at the same time, if you make the entire method synchronized, then they will get the singleton one by one (serial), if you use the normal double-checked locking pattern (and the singleton is already set), then all those 100 threads get the value concurrently (in parallel), because they never have to enter the synchronized block.

If the singleton has not been initialized yet, multiple threads will pass the first if, one thread enters the synchronized block to initialize the singleton, and the other threads wait on the synchronized block to enter. Once the first thread exits the synchronized block, the next thread waiting enters the synchronized block, but sees it is already initialized, and exits the synchronized block, etc. In the mean time, new threads asking for the singleton will never wait on the synchronized block, but instead get the value immediately.

@user85421 I was talking about any static method in the Singleton class not in the LazyHolder class, please check out this example: Singleton.

@RaduSebastianLAZIN but what you wrote ("the memory for singleton instance allocated even if you call another static method") is also true for "any static method" "in the LazyHolder class" -- exactly the same as would be the case for the Singleton class, and so the statement "as for in my example it is not" is not correct, or would also be valid for the Singleton class

@user85421 you are right I should have specified it in more detail, I hope now that I gave the example as well it is more clear. Of course if you implement a a static method even in the Singleton class that triggers the initialization (as @Holger pointed out) of the LazyHolder class the memory will be allocated also.


I was wondering if we could avoid the usage of volatile by making the
entire getInstance() method synchronized? If it does not work, how
would the execution of both cases differ?

It's possible and makes the code simpler, but has implications.
Example lazy-loaded Singleton using double-checked locking: https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/blob/master/singleton/src/main/java/com/iluwatar/singleton/ThreadSafeLazyLoadedIvoryTower.java
Example lazy-loaded Singleton using synchronized method: https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/blob/master/singleton/src/main/java/com/iluwatar/singleton/ThreadSafeLazyLoadedIvoryTower.java
The differences between these two:

Double-checked locking is more complex to implement and understand.
Double-checked locking is more performant since the whole method doesn't need to be synchronized. In the other version the method call is always synchronized even if the Singleton instance has already been created.

In summary, while double-checked locking is more complicated, it offers significant performance benefits in multi-threaded environments, making it preferable in scenarios where performance is a critical concern.


I was wondering if we could avoid the usage of volatile by making the entire getInstance() method synchronized? If it does not work, how would the execution of both cases differ?

Sure you can do that. But the point of the old DCL idiom was to avoid locking ... most of the time.  If you declare getInstance() as synchronized, it will acquire a lock each time you call the method.

The DCL idiom was invented back when Java locking was a lot more expensive.  These days, uncontended locking is (relatively) cheap, so hacks like DCL are less important.  Furthermore, there are other (better) idioms for implementing thread-safe initialization.  For example:

The initialization on demand holder idiom.

For a good Q&A on why the above works, see Initialization-on-demand holder idiom - When are classes loaded?.
